# Which system exception for Bad Request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have an API-controller that calls a service class. Inside the service class I want to throw an exception so the API-controller can catch it, and return a Http-BadRequest response. 
But what exception is equal to Bad Request? And what is best practise for this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used this pattern for throwing exceptions in the application layer and the api layer would recognize the http status code:

The exceptions definition:

```
public class BadRequestException : Exception
{
    public BadRequestException(string message = null)
        : base(message == null ? "Bad Request" : message)
    { }
}

public class ActionInputIsNotValidException : BadRequestException
{
    public ActionInputIsNotValidException()
        : base("Action input is not valid")
    { }
}
```

An Action Filter to handle exceptions in api layer:

```
public class ExceptionActionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public ExceptionActionFilter()
    {
    }

    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

        if (isTypeOf(context.Exception, typeof(Exceptions.BadRequestException)))
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        }

        context.Result = new JsonResult(new
        {
            Message = context.Exception.Message,
        });
    }

    private bool isTypeOf(Exception exception, Type baseType)
    {
        return exception.GetType() == baseType || exception.GetType().IsSubclassOf(baseType);
    }
}
```

Then in the application layer we can throw exceptions and the result of api call will be a json containing error message with http 400 status code:

```
throw new ActionInputIsNotValidException();
```

Comment: Does the filter get used by just adding the class to the project? Or does it need to be linked in somehow?